# Store external page source in Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Strictly using Javascript, is it possible to call a remote URL and store it in a variable?  To specify, this would not be on the same domain. Basically, what i am trying to figure out the best solution for scraping/parsing data in a chrome extension.

Comment: No, unless you're using `node.js` =)

Comment: Sure it is. Check out jQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

Comment: Where did your online research lead?

Comment: It led to stackoverflow, obviously ;)

Comment: Can you provide any more information than this? I can call a remote URL can store the URL in a variable, sure! I can even get the responseText from a same-domain page using XHR. I cannot load the HTML  from google.ca into a js variable via js.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to load the page from an external domain, you'll run into the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You can get around this limitation by setting up a simple proxy on your own site. This would be a bit of server-side code whose function is to make the http request to the external page on your behalf, retrieve the response, then serve that content back to the on-page asynchronous JavaScript code making the original request.

So if you set up your proxy at `/your_internal_proxy.foo`, and you're using jQuery, you could build a JS function something like this:

```
var foreignContent = {};
var loadPage = function(pageURL,varName) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '/your_internal_proxy.foo',
    data: {
      url_to_get: pageURL
    },
    success: function(result) {
      foreignContent[varName] = do_something_to( result );
    }
  });
};​
```

Then, to load content into JS variables:

```
loadPage('http://www.google.com/','goog');
loadPage('http://stackoverflow.com','stack');
```

Comment: ..or using JSONP, if the remote url supports it

Answer (score 1):

While Ajax may be the way to go it depends on what you mean by "remote URL".  Ajax will only work for url's with the same domain as the domain where the javascript originated from, due to Javascript cross-domain restrictions. There are various work arounds but most require the co-operation of the remote domain.  I've have heard of using YQL as an intermediary but have never tried it. Easiest is to host a proxy on your own server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use jQuery you can have something like:

```
  $.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Also the $.get() can be used to achieve this

> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$.get("test.html",
   function(data){
   // do something with response data
   });
```

Comment: Well, if "remote URL" is "the same domain", then certainly yes.

Comment: agree :) but since he hasn't specified any other details i assume that it was the same domain

Comment: Yea, assumption of innocence ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it wouldn't be the same domain. I edited my question. Silly me in my hasty frustration.

Comment: in this case check @Ken Redler cause he has the answer for you